# Hibernate, trying to access grandchild fields one to many relationship

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have the following structure in my database:

[image]

I've mapped them in hibernate configuration files like this:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="model.CartEntity" table="cart">
        <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <set name="products" table="cart_product_record" 
            inverse="true" lazy="false" fetch="select" cascade="save-update, delete">
            <key>
                <column name="cart_id" not-null="false" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="model.ProductRecordEntity" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<hibernate-mapping>
   <class name="model.ProductRecordEntity" table="product_record">
      <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
         <generator class="native"/>
      </id>
      <many-to-one name="product" class="model.ProductEntity" fetch="select" cascade="save-update, delete">
          <column name="product_id" />
      </many-to-one>
      <many-to-one name="cart" class="model.CartEntity" fetch="select" cascade="save-update, delete">
          <column name="cart_id" not-null="true" />
       </many-to-one>
   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="model.ProductEntity" table="product">
        <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <set name="productRecords" table="product_record_product" inverse="true"
        lazy="false" fetch="select" cascade="save-update, delete">
            <key>
                <column name="product_id" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="model.ProductRecordEntity" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I retrieve from the database the cart which has all the product records, no problem so far, I get all the necessary data correctly.

```
CartEntity cart = findById(id);
List<ProductRecordEntity> productRecords = cart.getProductRecords();
```

The problem is when I try to get the product from the product record:

```
for (ProductRecordEntity productRecord: productRecords){
    ProductEntity product = productRecord.getProduct();
}
```

I get an object with all fields with their default value, not the information from database.

When saving the entities in the database, the ids are populated correctly.

Product record table:

[image]

And the product table:

[image]

These are the entities:

```
public class CartEntity {

    private int id;

    private Set<ProductRecordEntity> products = new HashSet<ProductRecordEntity>();

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Set<ProductRecordEntity> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    public void setProducts(Set<ProductRecordEntity> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }
}


public class ProductRecordEntity {
    private int id;

    private CartEntity cart;

    private ProductEntity product;

    public CartEntity getCart() {
        return cart;
    }

    public void setCart(CartEntity cart) {
        this.cart = cart;
    }

    public ProductEntity getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(ProductEntity product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
     }
}


public class ProductEntity implements Serializable{
    private int id;

    private Set<ProductRecordEntity> productRecords;

    public Set<ProductRecordEntity> getProductRecords() {
        return productRecords;
    }

    public void setProductRecords(Set<ProductRecordEntity> productRecords) {
        this.productRecords = productRecords;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

This is the order of operations on the database:

```
    persist(cartEntity);
    persist(productEntity);

    productRecordEntity.setCartEntity(cartEntity);
    cartEntity.getProducts().add(productRecordEntity);

    productRecordEntity.setProduct(productEntity);
    persist(productRecordEntity);

    productEntity.getProductRecords().add(productRecordEntity);
    update(productEntity);

   update(cartEntity);
```

Any idea what I'm missing? I can't find where the problem is, I've double, triple checked everything.

Comment: Could you please post your Product model class and the DAO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding lazy="false" to the ProductOrder xml mapping.

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="model.ProductOrderEntity" table="product_order">
        <id name="id" type="int" column="product_order_id">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="quantity" column="quantity" type="int" />
        <property name="price" column="price" type="java.lang.Float" />
        <many-to-one name="product" class="model.ProductEntity"
        fetch="select" lazy="false">
            <column name="product_id" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="order" class="model.OrderEntity"
        fetch="select" lazy="false">
            <column name="order_id" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I think it's an initialization problem, when getting the product records from the database I should initialize the product field while the session is still opened, like this:

```
Hibernate.initialize(product);
```

Answer (score 0):

for CartEntity and ProductEntity mapping, why are you using association tables? you should use table="product_record".